# Running hadoop mapreduce job from java program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to invoke a mapreduce job from my java code. It that possible?

I was trying to run

```
    ToolRunner.run(new Validation(), pathsMoveToFinal.toArray(new String[pathsMoveToFinal.size()]));
```

from my code.
But when I was trying to run, it gives warning:

```
[Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable]
```

and just stuck there.

Could anyone please give me some suggestion?

Comment: Could you post more of your code and perhaps any configuration you have? Just a small snippet doesn't give us much to work with.

Comment: Don't worry about that warning, Hadoop should still work without the native libraries. If Hadoop is running, go to http://localhost:50030/ - you'll see a list of all the jobs that have been started, and you'll be able to read their logs.

Comment: And read this, if you haven't already: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/quickstart.html

Comment: Also, check the log files where the program got stuck.